# Jquery function not setting/calculating correct date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to set a field to a number of weeks from today date using a select box. But it keeps setting the date to today.

This is the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="rfq[ship_date]" id="rfq_ship_date" class="hasDatepicker">

<select name="weeks" id="weeks">
        <option value="1">1 weeks</option>
        <option value="2">2 weeks</option>
        <option value="3">3 weeks</option>
        <option value="4">4 weeks</option>
        .....
```

I have this for the javascript

```
$ ->
  today = new Date

  $('#weeks').change ->
    weeks = $(this).val()
    $('#rfq_ship_date').val(today + (weeks*1000*3600*24*7))

 return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add milliseconds and turn to date again.

Instead of

```
$('#rfq_ship_date').val(today + (weeks*1000*3600*24*7))
```

Use

```
$('#rfq_ship_date').val(new Date(today.getTime() + (weeks * 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it.  But why does that make a difference?

Comment: @suavocado If you use `+` with a `Date`, it gets converted to a string and performs concatenation, not date/time arithmetic.

Comment: Try `console.log(new Date + 12345)` and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can add days directly to a date with `getDate` and `setDate`:

```
new_date = new Date;
new_date.setDate(new_date.getDate() + weeks * 7);
$("#rfq_ship_date").val(new_date);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works as well.  Is there functionally any difference between your answer and cpshah's?  The only reason I'm leaving it as the other answer is because I have a lot of fields that use the .val function and it helps me organize them (and I have to eventually explain this to a coworker as well).  Have an upvote for your time though!

Comment: No, there's no significant difference. I think mine is a little more understandable, because you don't have to figure out what all the multiplications are doing.